# How to pass json on res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to pass token to callback on `res.redirect`, but im getting

> Cannot GET /api/users/auth/github/200

I need it to redirect, as well.

```
router.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github',  { session: true, scope: ['profile'] }) );

router.get('/auth/github/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    var token = jwt.sign({ id: req.user.id},  'nodeauthsecret');
    res.cookie("jwt", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10*1000*60*60*24)});
    // res.status(200).send({ authenticated: true});

    // res.status(200).send({
    //   message: 'user signed in', 
    //   token:token
    // });

    res.redirect(200, 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/dashboard', {message:'user signed in', token: token});
    console.log(token)
    console.log('this works');
});
```

Comment: A non-3xx status isn't a redirect, so I'd guess the 200 is being treated as a relative path to redirect to. Also `res.redirect` doesn't take a third argument (per [the API docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)).

Comment: how would i be able to achieve a redirect with sending a json message ?

Comment: You could use the regular res.send, but note that a redirect is just asking the client to make a new request; they may not read the body (a 304 redirect must not have a body, in fact). The token is already in the cookie, and success can be inferred by the fact that it's set and you're sending them on to the next step.